# Sharable component in multiple react apps

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-dev-server, react-boilerplate

What is the best way to develop two independent react apps by using sharble components ?

**Ex.** App1 and App2

```
App1 would conatains
 index.html
 app1.js

App2 would conatins
 index.html
 app2.js
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a React UI library. Basically an NPM module with all your shared components. You can then npm install this module into whatever app requires those components.

Have a look at [creating an NPM module](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules)

and [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) is great for developing UI libraries.